# What do hollow blue circles with a dot mean on the World Map?

Tags: dead-cells

During a 2 Boss Stem Cell run, I noticed some biomes on the World Map were marked by sets of hollow blue circles that had a dot inside and were connected together. When selecting a marked location, I could not see paths showing which biomes the area was connected to. The marked biomes were Cavern, Guardian's Haven, Astrolab, and Observatory.

What do these hollow blue dotted circles indicate?

[image: Cavern on the World map marked by blue circles]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These blue circles are only cosmetic and the whole border is just here to indicate that these biomes are part of the Rise of the Giant DLC.

Each biome coming from a specific DLC has its own specific border to identify from which DLC it's from.

Comment: Ah, the circles are part of the DLC border. I knew the gems were part of it, but I had assumed the circles were something different.